# Complex integral with different contours

Tags: complex-integration

If I have a complex integral to solve using the Cauchy Integral formula with the same point but with different contours, in which the point used is inside both contours, is the result the same?

Say for example that I have
$$
\int_C \frac{dz}{(z+i)(z-i)}
$$

with two different contours:

1. $\|z-i\|=1$
2. A square of size 2 centered in $z=i$

In this case, one contour is a circunference and the other is a square, both centered in $z=i$, which I use when applying the Cauchy Integral formula.

Is it right that both will result in $\pi$ as the result? Or is there a difference when you use different contours?

Comment: The results will be the same in this case

Comment: do you mean "a square of side 2 centered at $z=i$"? "size 2" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the poles enclosed by each contour.

Comment: What would be different if one contour encloses a pole and the other doesn't?

Comment: @GustavoAmgarten: If there is no a pole inside the contour then check [Cauchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: This has meaning for those who know the answer, but for those who don't, perhaps not so much. Mentioning Cauchy's Theorem or [The Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) **in the answer** would be better.